# Can I get Google Now reminders to be sent via email or popup on desktop gmail as well?

Tags: google-now

My primary workflow revolves around my desktop, and my Gmail.

Is there a wait to get Google Now to interpret "Remind me to do laundry in 2 hours", as "Don't just blip on my phone where I may not be paying attention, but also popup on my calendar and email me"?

Comment: P.S I usually would send myself an email to 2hours@followupthen.com if I'm on a desktop and I want to remind myself something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Google Now, because I don't use it.

But if it's getting the data from the Calendar, then it's possible to create an email notification.

[image]

You can also set this via [Google Calendar web app](http://calendar.google.com/).

[image]